# How to avoid updating child table when data is null or blank?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have entity parent in which I am using `@SecondoryTable`. Secondary table have one info as attribute. Now when I save parent, child is saving automatically.

But I don't want to save child if child data is null. I want to save parent but not child in that case. Which annotation should I use to fixed this in entity?

Comment: You can try to use the [@DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-dynamicupdate) annotation, but I am not sure that it will work with `@SecondoryTable` properly

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

If you want to have the relation optional you must use a `@OneToOne` relationship instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using below approach.

In your parent entity where you have defined `@SecondoryTable` there you have suppose child column so during parent save you need to set the null value in parent for that child attribute.